# Twilio SMS Error - Status 401, Code 20003

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm trying to send SMS using Twilio in my Node.js application, and I'm encountering an issue.

```
const twilioClient = twilio(TWILIO_SID, TWILIO_TOKEN, {
    logLevel: 'debug',
});

const message = await twilioClient.messages.create({
    to: toNumber,
    from: `${TWILIO_NUMBER}`,
    body: `Hi`,
});
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "status": 401,
    "code": 20003,
    "moreInfo": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003"
}
```

I have checked the Twilio documentation for the error code 20003, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue. Can someone please guide me on how to fix this authentication problem?

Comment: As you sure you use the right account sid and auth token?

Comment: yes, when i use same cred with java it works

Comment: Can you `console.log(TWILIO_SID, TWILIO_TOKEN)` to check if the credentials are set properly (no trailing spaces etc)

Comment: yes, no trailing spaces, i'm able to console